# Prove this matrix is a subspace of M4,1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble solving this problem, do I use Cramer's Rule to write a general form of set B and go from there?

" Consider the vector space M4,4. I have a specific matrix A in M4,4 but I’m not revealing what it is (it actually doesn’t matter what it is for this problem, just know that there is a specific matrix). Consider
the set of all matrices B in M4,1 that solve the equation AB = 5B . This set forms a subspace of M4,1. Prove that it is a subspace of M4,1. "

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyyw0.png)

Comment: It's not clear why the question asks you to consider the subspace $M_{4,4}$. Also, it's strange to say "I have a specific matrix but I'm not revealing what it is". Just a strangely asked question all around.

Comment: And no, you shouldn't have to do anything involving Cramer's Rule to show that the set forms a vector space, you just need the definition of a subspace and the equation $AB = 5B$ that defines this set

Comment: Yeah, I guess the wording just made it more difficult for me to understand what I'm doing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to go about solving this problem, but ultimately what you need to show is that this set, i.e. the solution space to the equation $AB = 5B$ (over $B$), passes the test for a set to be a linear subspace.

There are two conditions that a subset needs to satisfy: it needs to be closed under scalar multiplication and closed under addition. Let's show that the set is closed under addition – let $B_1,B_2$ be two different elements of this set (i.e. $B = B_1$ and $B = B_2$ are solutions in $M_{4,1}$ to the equation $AB = 5B$). We want to show that $B = B_1 + B_2$ is also a solution to that same equation. To that end, note that
$$
A(B_1 + B_2) = AB_1 + AB_2 = 5B_1 + 5B_2 = 5(B_1 + B_2).
$$
So, we indeed find that $B = B_1 + B_2$ is a solution to the equation. So, our solution set is closed under addition.

Now, try to show that this set is closed under scalar multiplication. That is, for any solution $B$ to the equation and any number $k$, the matrix $kB$ will also be a solution to the equation.